# Highly accurate Geolocation in iOS 9 or 10 using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, location

looking for the most accurate Geolocation code to use in Javascript for iOS 9 or 10

Comment: ohhh..this is not an iOS related query. As a beginner, make question in descriptive manner. Show some of your work you have done.  Now which platform are you using. Below is link for Cordova http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/

Comment: @Gagan_iOS theoretically if OP is using cordova or not it shouldnt matter. The Geolocation webapi should always return the same location as the device api

Answer (score 0):

Geolocation on a device is always dependent on the device itself. Which means that only if a device has the accurate location locked it will always have an offset

you should use the [Geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) documentation to get the current position:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
});
```

Comment: it is nit accurate when using iPhone ios9 or 10